# Como inserir um web snippet em uma aplicação react js

Tags: javascript, react

Preciso inserir um web-snippet fornecido pela [Delighted](https://delighted.com) para pesquisa de NPS. Sei que o React trabalha com a questão de componentes, e é provável que importar um script js direto seja uma má prática. Mas enfim, como fazer essa integração? O snippet serve para abrir um popup e receber avaliação dos usuários/visitantes ao site.

Segue trecho do snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  !function(e,t,r,n){if(!e[n]){for(var a=e[n]=[],i=["survey","reset","config","init","set","get","event","identify","track","page","screen","group","alias"],s=0;s<i.length;s++){var c=i[s];a[c]=a[c]||function(e){return function(){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);a.push([e,t])}}(c)}a.SNIPPET_VERSION="1.0.1";var o=t.createElement("script");o.type="text/javascript",o.async=!0,o.src="https://d2yyd1h5u9mauk.cloudfront.net/integrations/web/v1/library/"+r+"/"+n+".js";var p=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];p.parentNode.insertBefore(o,p)}}(window,document,"Fy3OJMEqXnqCoQxs","delighted");

  delighted.survey({
    email: "customer@hemandstitch.com", // customer email (optional)
    name: "Bailey Dixon",               // customer name (optional)
    properties: {                       // extra context (optional)
      orderId: "123ABC",
      shippingMethod: "Ground"
    }
  });;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar isso no `index.html` ou colocar essa função em um arquivo (por boa prática) e importa-lo na base da app React (o arquivo em que você usa o `ReactDOM.render`)